# Network not working after update to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu-16.04

I updated a server from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. As expected, I had to rename my network interfaces fron *eth0*, etc to *eno1*, etc. However, of the two interfaces (one 'internal' and one 'external'), only one (internal) is working.
I also have a kvm bridge configured so the internal interface is running the bridge.

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

auto br1
iface br1 inet static
    address yyy.yyy.yyy.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway yyy.yyy.yyy.254
    bridge_waitport 30
    bridge_ports eno1
    bridge_fd 1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 3330

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
   address xxx.xxx.xxx.169
   netmask 255.255.255.248
   broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.175
   gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.174
```

Since I suddenly had problems with the second gateway (RTNETLINK answers: File exists), I manually defined the route

ip route show:

```
default via xxx.xxx.xxx.174 dev eno2
default via yyy.yyy.yyy.254 dev br1 onlink
yyy.yyy.yyy.0/24 dev br1  proto kernel  scope link  src yyy.yyy.yy.2
xxx.xxx.xxx.168/29 dev eno2  proto kernel  scope link  src xxx.xxx.xxx.169
```

Interface *br1* works great, *eno2* does absolutely nothing. I cannot get in or out on this interface.
I also checked the router output and the correct MAC and IP address are in the correct VLAN.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the case but do you ensure you had bridge-utils installed after the update?

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
```